# jQuery: do I need to put calls to $("img").lazyload() in $(document).ready()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using [lazy load jquery plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload).

It tells me to put this in my code to activate it:

```
$("img").lazyload();
```

Do I have to put this in `$(document).ready()`? or can I just put it at the very top of the page:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
$("img").lazyload();

$(document).ready...{}

</script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [demo page](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled.html) puts it in the $(document).ready(), except it uses the shorthand $( ) function to do it.

(from the demo)

```
$( function() {
    $("img").lazyload({placeholder : "img/grey.gif"});
} );
```

(note that $() is an alias to the [jQuery()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery3) function, which takes CSS selectors, HTML elements and *also* callbacks to run when the DOM loads)

If you don't put it in the ready() function, then it may only affect images that are earlier in the page than your script. And if you're placing scripts in the HEAD, that's none of the images.

So, unless the library is somehow using the .live() function of JQuery, you need to put it in ready().

Comment: Maybe I am wrong about how .live() works? Or about putting the script halfway down the page? Who knows!

Comment: @kibibu, possibly, but my question wasn't to you, as such, but I was hoping that whoever down-voted might explain *why* they did so. Or, failing that, someone who knows more about js/jQuery than me, might explain.

Comment: Random anonymous down-votes is one of the most fun things about stackoverflow.

Comment: @kibibu, it's one of the many reasons that I think actions should be *owned* by whoever takes those actions. It works well for *closing* questions, I don't see why it'd be a problem for down-voting an answer. I think it'd encourage more reasonable behaviour.

Comment: I just came back to this question to see what I downvoted. I changed it to +1 instead of -1. I must've fat fingered this accidentally. The buttons are hard to deal with on mobile phones. Sorry about this.

Answer (score 3):

The way I understand it is that if you put it in the `$(document).ready(...)` the script won't run until the DOM has loaded. If you just put it in `<script></script>` tags in the `head` then the page will have to wait for the script to complete before the remainder of the DOM can load.

If the script modifies the DOM this means it will run, do nothing, then the page will load (having not been affected by the `$("img").lazyload()` function.

Comment: @alex, well, to be fair, I've already gained more rep than @kibibu for some reason. Despite the non-acceptance. =)

Answer (score 2):

You **should** put it in the $(document).ready().

Answer (score 0):

You need to put it inside since it uses jQuery library.

Comment: I'm fairly new to jQuery/js so, if I'm wrong, be nice? But once the jQuery library's loaded aren't the functions therein accessible, so long as they're in an appropriate form, available to all scripts in the calling page so long as they're within the appropriate `<script>` tags?

Comment: Just because it uses jquery, that doesn't mean it needs to go inside.